# How to Order by Scope function and then by a field

Tags: angularjs

How can I order by `getTotal()` and then by quantity descending?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="shop">
   <head>
      <script 
         src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-controller='productCtrl'>
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in products| orderBy:'price'">
               {{x.quantity}} {{x.Name}} 
               <strong>{{ (x.quantity*x.price)|currency}}</strong>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <p>Total = {{ (getTotal()) | currency }}</p>
      </div>
      <script>
         var app=angular.module("shop",[])
         .controller('productCtrl',function($scope){
              $scope.products=[{quantity:4,price:42.3,Name:"HDD Sata"},
                     {quantity:14,price:2.83,Name:"USB Key"},
                     {quantity:5,price:11.03,Name:"Azerty Keyboard"},
                     {quantity:1,price:4.3,Name:"Mouse"}];
              $scope.getTotal=function(){
                  var sum=0;
                  for(var i=0;i<$scope.products.length;i++){
           sum+=($scope.products[i].price*$scope.products[i].quantity);
         }
                  return sum;
              }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to order by `getTotal()` then that function will return only one value (total of all the item values) so there is no useful of using that function to order. I think you need to order by item totals instead of all item total:

try this one,

Ex: consider following data

```
 $scope.products = [{
  quantity: 4,
  price: 1,
  Name: "HDD Sata"
}, {
  quantity: 2,
  price: 2,
  Name: "USB Key"
}, {
  quantity: 5,
  price: 11.03,
  Name: "Azerty Keyboard"
}, {
  quantity: 1,
  price: 4.3,
  Name: "Mouse"
}];
```

I think you need `HDD Sata` on top and `Azerty Keyboard` on bottom, because total price for `HDD Sata` is `$4.00` meanwhile `USB Key` also `$4.00` but `HDD Sata` has `4 quantity` while `USB Key` has `2 quantity` and u need quantity to be `DESCENDING` so `HDD Sata` in top of `USB Key`. `Azerty Keyboard` has subtotal of `$55.15` which is highest total for a item and its in bottom.

in HTML,

```
<li ng-repeat="x in products| orderBy:[getTotalForItem, '-quantity'] ">
```

in Controller,

```
$scope.getTotalForItem = function(item) {
  return item.price * item.quantity;
}
```

here is the [demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YIMUj1yh3H8pl7HoIZ1C?p=preview)